# Trying to convert from a 'hover' CSS transition to similar javascript functionality. And failing

Tags: javascript, html, css, coldfusion

I am so sorry to have to post a somewhat noobish (probably syntax) question, but I have been grinding on this thing for hours today. I have been all over the internet, including many posts on this site and I'm just not finding what I need (or so I think.) The problem is likely my inexperience with javascript. I'm hoping someone can tell me where my mistake is.

Background - the web app that I'm working on is hosted on a ColdFusion 2016 server. I don't think that's necessarily relevant for this particular piece, but perhaps.

I have an icon, which on hover "slides out" a 'Quick Notes' panel (by transitioning the right: property in CSS from -500px to 500px). Here the user can enter notes in a RTF text area, then submit to update their record in the user table. This is working fine.

Here is the relevant CSS for the icon (notes_slideout) and the main notes section (notes_slideout_inner), along with the hover stuff which works fine.

```
#notes_slideout {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 104px;
        right: 0;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #454545;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 
            0 2px 2px 0px black;
        z-index:1; 
    }

    #notes_slideout_inner {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 104px;
        top: 35px;
        right: -500px;
        background: #454545;
        width: 500px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        height: auto;
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: white;
        font-size:18px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        vertical-align:center;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        box-shadow:
            0 2px 2px 0px black; 
        z-index:1;
    }



#notes_slideout:hover {
        right: 500px;
        z-index:1;
    }

    #notes_slideout:hover #notes_slideout_inner {
        right: 0;
        z-index:1;
    }
```

The problem with this setup is that if the user hovers away/loses focus from the slideout_inner div, say by clicking on the text area to enter a note, it slides back to the right as designed.

What I am trying to do is use onClick and have javascript do essentially the same CSS settings changes and switch the button function.

Here is the tag I have on the image:

```
    <img src="/#sys_var#/resources/images/notepad_icon.png" alt="Notes" height="32" onClick="openNotes()"/>
```

And here are the functions as I have them defined:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function openNotes() {
    document.getElementById("notes_slideout_inner").style.right = "500px";
    document.getElementById("notes_slideout").onClick = "closeNotes()";

}

function closeNotes() {
    document.getElementById("notes_slideout_inner").style.right: = "-500px";
    document.getElementById("notes_slideout").style.right: = "0px";
    document.getElementById("notes_slideout").onClick = "openNotes()";
}
</script>
```

I have experimented with adding/removing the

> type="text/javascript"

from the script tag (none of our other working functions have it), as well as making the onClick look like this:

> onClick="javascript:openNotes()"

Same results for both.

So when I go to test, I comment out those last two 'hover' sections in the CSS  and the hover is broken (as expected) and the button appears to do nothing when you click it. However, upon inspection it is generating an error -

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'matches'
```

And just now a brand new-error I am just seeing for the first time:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'openNotes' is undefined
```

Thank you so very much for any insight you can share. If there is more relevant code you think I should have included, I am happy to post it. This app is super-complicated, so I tried to just strip out and provide the relevant pieces and I may have overlooked something. I so appreciate everyone on this site. You have saved me time and again over the years.

Edit: not sure how I missed this one but it looks like it may work?

> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css

```
#notes_slideout {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 104px;
            right: 0;
            width: 32px;
            height: 32px;
            padding: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            background: #454545;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
            -o-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 
                0 2px 2px 0px black;
            z-index:1; 
        }

        #notes_slideout_inner {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 104px;
            top: 35px;
            right: -500px;
            background: #454545;
            width: 500px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            height: auto;
            text-decoration: none; 
            color: white;
            font-size:18px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            vertical-align:center;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
            -o-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            box-shadow:
                0 2px 2px 0px black; 
            z-index:1;
        }
```

html

```
<div id="notes_slideout" onclick="toggleNotes()">            
</div>
<div id="notes_slideout_inner">
</div>
```

javascript

```
function toggleNotes() {                  
  if (elm("notes_slideout").style.right == "0px") {
    elm("notes_slideout").style.right = "500px";
    elm("notes_slideout_inner").style.right = "0px";
  } else {
    elm("notes_slideout").style.right = "0px";
    elm("notes_slideout_inner").style.right = "-500px";
  }
}


function elm(elementId) {
    return document.getElementById(elementId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have positioned the inner div `#notes_slideout_inner`  with `top:32px;` which is the size of outer div `#notes_slideout` i.e, `width:32px`.

Hence whenever you hover over the outer div and try to attain `:hover` on the inner div which is already 32px below the place you hovered. Hence it slides back.

Maybe what you are looking for:

```css
#notes_slideout {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 104px;
        right: 0;
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #454545;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px; 
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        box-shadow: 
            0 2px 2px 0px black;
        z-index:1; 
    }

    #notes_slideout_inner {
        position: absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  height:500px;
  width:500px;
        top: 0;
        right: -500px;
        background: #454545;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: white;
        font-size:18px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        vertical-align:center;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
        -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
        -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
        box-shadow:
            0 2px 2px 0px black; 
        z-index:10;
    }



#notes_slideout:hover {
        right: 500px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="notes_slideout">
 <div id="notes_slideout_inner">
  <input />
 </div>
</div>
```